# How to optimize the KASUMI cipher S-boxes?

Tags: c, cryptography, lookup-tables

I am trying to optimizing the `Kasumi crypto` algorithm written in C.
There are S-box which uses to encrypt the data. which I am representing as an array in which is huge:

```
int S7[128] = {
   54, 50, 62, 56, 22, 34, 94, 96, 38,  6, 63, 93,  2, 18,123, 33,
   55,113, 39,114, 21, 67, 65, 12, 47, 73, 46, 27, 25,111,124, 81,
   53,  9,121, 79, 52, 60, 58, 48,101,127, 40,120,104, 70, 71, 43,
   20,122, 72, 61, 23,109, 13,100, 77,  1, 16,  7, 82, 10,105, 98,
  117,116, 76, 11, 89,106,  0,125,118, 99, 86, 69, 30, 57,126, 87,
  112, 51, 17,  5, 95, 14, 90, 84, 91,  8, 35,103, 32, 97, 28, 66,
  102, 31, 26, 45, 75,  4, 85, 92, 37, 74, 80, 49, 68, 29,115, 44,
   64,107,108, 24,110, 83, 36, 78, 42, 19, 15, 41, 88,119, 59,  3
};

int S9[512] = {
  167,239,161,379,391,334,  9,338, 38,226, 48,358,452,385, 90,397,
  183,253,147,331,415,340, 51,362,306,500,262, 82,216,159,356,177,
  175,241,489, 37,206, 17,  0,333, 44,254,378, 58,143,220, 81,400,
   95,  3,315,245, 54,235,218,405,472,264,172,494,371,290,399, 76,
  165,197,395,121,257,480,423,212,240, 28,462,176,406,507,288,223,
  501,407,249,265, 89,186,221,428,164, 74,440,196,458,421,350,163,
  232,158,134,354, 13,250,491,142,191, 69,193,425,152,227,366,135,
  344,300,276,242,437,320,113,278, 11,243, 87,317, 36, 93,496, 27,
  487,446,482, 41, 68,156,457,131,326,403,339, 20, 39,115,442,124,
  475,384,508, 53,112,170,479,151,126,169, 73,268,279,321,168,364,
  363,292, 46,499,393,327,324, 24,456,267,157,460,488,426,309,229,
  439,506,208,271,349,401,434,236, 16,209,359, 52, 56,120,199,277,
  465,416,252,287,246,  6, 83,305,420,345,153,502, 65, 61,244,282,
  173,222,418, 67,386,368,261,101,476,291,195,430, 49, 79,166,330,
  280,383,373,128,382,408,155,495,367,388,274,107,459,417, 62,454,
  132,225,203,316,234, 14,301, 91,503,286,424,211,347,307,140,374,
   35,103,125,427, 19,214,453,146,498,314,444,230,256,329,198,285,
   50,116, 78,410, 10,205,510,171,231, 45,139,467, 29, 86,505, 32,
   72, 26,342,150,313,490,431,238,411,325,149,473, 40,119,174,355,
  185,233,389, 71,448,273,372, 55,110,178,322, 12,469,392,369,190,
    1,109,375,137,181, 88, 75,308,260,484, 98,272,370,275,412,111,
  336,318,  4,504,492,259,304, 77,337,435, 21,357,303,332,483, 18,
   47, 85, 25,497,474,289,100,269,296,478,270,106, 31,104,433, 84,
  414,486,394, 96, 99,154,511,148,413,361,409,255,162,215,302,201,
  266,351,343,144,441,365,108,298,251, 34,182,509,138,210,335,133,
  311,352,328,141,396,346,123,319,450,281,429,228,443,481, 92,404,
  485,422,248,297, 23,213,130,466, 22,217,283, 70,294,360,419,127,
  312,377,  7,468,194,  2,117,295,463,258,224,447,247,187, 80,398,
  284,353,105,390,299,471,470,184, 57,200,348, 63,204,188, 33,451,
   97, 30,310,219, 94,160,129,493, 64,179,263,102,189,207,114,402,
  438,477,387,122,192, 42,381,  5,145,118,180,449,293,323,136,380,
   43, 66, 60,455,341,445,202,432,  8,237, 15,376,436,464, 59,461
};
```

During the encryption we are accessing this array very frequently.
One optimization which I had done moving this array from header file to local function so that some cache miss will not happened.

Any suggestion to more optimize this either by changing this array to any other data structure?

Comment: Why would header vs. function affect cache performance?

Comment: But FYI, if you're working on a typical 32-bit platform, `int` is twice as much space as you really need.  You could halve your cache usage by switching to `int16_t`.

Comment: put s7 and s3 in the same contiguous array to provide spacial locality of reference, might be a micro optimization

Comment: @UmNyobe: Why might that improve things?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: In fact, even `int8_t` (or `uint8_t`) would work for the `S7` array. The `S9` array needs at least 9 bits per entry, though.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth in header file it will be treated as a global variable whether it will local in a function that will increase the cache performance. i have tested it and yes performance has increased.

Comment: @RATHI: I don't think that follows.  In either case, your array is simply a chunk of contiguous memory.  So the cache performance would be the same.  The only way I can see this making a difference is if you are accessing elements with constant indices, (e.g. `S7[23]` as opposed to `S7[i]`), where the compiler could perform constant folding in one case and not the other.  But that's still not a cache effect.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth i am not sure about the reason but performance of program has increased.

Comment: If you need to use Kasumi in CTR mode it could be a good idea to switch to a bitsliced implementation.

Answer (score 2):

that array is not huge.  a typical L1 cache is at least 10s of kB (that's the total memory on, say, an apple ii).  and moving the array from a header to a function is not going to change cache locality.

storing it in the appropriate form (as in comments) may make sense (it's going to fit in l1 cache, but if you have other data, perhaps used by another thread, there's more chance of it staying there) - there's no need for more than 2 bytes per value (but i have no idea if that introduces extra cost compared to using native size ints).

if this is really critical, you should look at the code generated and optimize that.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure you declare those arrays as `const`, so that the compiler knows they'll never change.

Second, as Oli Charlesworth suggests in the comments, you don't really need a full `int` to store each value.  The elements of the `S7` and `S9` arrays are 7-bit and 9-bit unsigned integers, so either of `int8_t` or `uint8_t` should be enough for `S7`, and either of `int16_t` or `uint16_t` for `S9`.  (You may want to benchmark whether there's any difference between using signed or unsigned types, although I wouldn't really expect any.)

Finally, if you *really* want to get rid of the arrays entirely, it's also possible to implement the KASUMI S-boxes directly without *any* lookup tables, using bit operations (specifically, AND and XOR).  For details, see pages 13–16 of the [KASUMI specification](http://www.garykessler.net/library/crypto/3G_KASUMI.pdf).  However, I strongly suspect that this will not be useful for a software implementation, unless you're using [bit-slicing](http://plaintext.crypto.lo.gy/en/article/378/untwisted-bit-sliced-tea-time) to encrypt many blocks in parallel.